# I cannot upate firebase document while iterating through an array

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to build settings in my app. I want to update permissions for every member of each team when team seetings change. I wanted to solve the problem using transaction. First I get members array from team document then loop through that array and update every single member permissions. I found out that I cant update documents in that forEach loop inside the transaction.

I tried to push every docRef and settings data of every member to an array and inside another forEach loop update them. But I encoutered another problem despite the fact that I have `await` before looping through the members array it don't work because readyMembers array is empty. If I update the array before `const user = await transaction.get(docRef);` then it is updated. And I tried to log "TEST" at the end of each loop and the readyMembers array was loged first and then "TEST", so it seems that `await` doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
await runTransaction(db, async (transaction) => {      
        const data = await transaction.get(doc(db, `trainingGroups/${id}`));
        const members = data.data().members;
        let readyMembers=[];
        await members.forEach(async (member) => {
          const docRef = doc(db, `users/${member.id}`);
          const user = await transaction.get(docRef);
          const userSettings = user.data().settings;
          if (
            settings.isAllowedMembersInvitations &&
            !userSettings.permissions.includes({ id: id, type: "invitations" })
          ) {
            userSettings.permissions = [
              ...userSettings.permissions,
              { id: id, type: "invitations" },
            ];
          } else if (!settings.isAllowedMembersInvitations) {
            userSettings.permissions.filter(
              (permission) => permission.id !== id || type !== "invitations"
            );
          }
          readyMembers.push({ref: docRef,settings: userSettings});
          console.log("TEST");
        });
        console.log(readyMembers);
        readyMembers.forEach((member)=>{
          console.log(member);
          transaction.update(member.ref,{settings: member.settings});
        })
      });
```

If there is another way to update permissions of every single member I am open to new solutions.

Comment: forEach doesn't return a promise, so you can't await it. And any async function you call in the forEach isn't going to cause the loop to wait for it to complete. The loop will complete before any of the async work actually starts. You will need a completely different pattern to do this correctly (such as for/of), which are discussed in the duplicate.